# What is the pronunciation of O with macron and breve?

Tags: pronunciation, diacritics

I found an Indo-European root, *nō̆-men-*, in [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=n%C5%8D%CC%86-men-).

I know both macron and breve mean the length of vowels. And the Latin word, *nōmen*, has a long *ō*.

However, how should I pronounce the vowel with macron and breve simultaneously?

Comment: This question asks about the interpretation of an (reconstructed) Indo-European root, not about Latin language. My best guess is that the reconstruction isn't clear whether the o should be long or short and this uncertainty is expressed by displaying both diacritics.

Comment: Yes, macron and breve means "this vowel may be short or long" -- either because we don't know which, or because both variants appeared in different forms of the word.

Comment: @jknappen and TKR, Thank you for teaching me the meaning. I want to hear that. Sorry for posting the question to the wrong category.

Comment: I think the question could be on topic--it's obviously the root of Latin *nomen*, which has a long *-o*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Either as a long vowel or as a short one...but linguists aren't entirely sure which.

This root appears in Latin (and other languages) with a long ō, *nōmen*, but in Greek (and others) with a short o, *ónoma*. So it's not entirely clear whether the PIE vowel was long or short. We know it was one or the other, but there's not a consensus on which one.

One theory is that it was short in PIE, and became long separately in Indo-Iranian (via Brugmann's Law), Germanic (via Germanic ablaut), and Latin (by analogy with other words: for example, *cōgnōmen* looks like *cognōsco*, which is from a separate root with a long ō). But Brugmann's Law is far from universally accepted, and others argue that the root had a long ō which became short in some languages.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the meaning of the diacritics. And sorry for posting the question to the wrong category. I didn't notice the difference between roots and Latin words.

Comment: Maybe I should ask this question in http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: @nekketsuuu, if you think your question would be better at Linguistics (and if the people there agree), it can be migrated there. The question can be related to Latin as well: macron and breve together sometimes mark ambiguity, and the root is related to the Latin word *nomen*. If you could edit the question a bit to relate it to Latin somehow, it would certainly be on-topic.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thank you for the advice! I edited my question.

Comment: Isn't it simply PIE ablaut? Zero-grade *h3 gives short o, e-grade *eh3 gives long o, and different languages generalized different grades.

Comment: Btw I was surprised by the statement that Brugmann's Law is controversial, so I posted a [question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/is-brugmanns-law-controversial) about it on Linguistics SE.

Answer (score 3):

The linked entry in “the free dictionary” has the lemma as “nō̆-men-“, but then proceeds to claim “oldest form *h1no(h3)-mn̥”. If *h1no(h3)-mn̥ is Proto-Indo-European (PIE) what language is nō̆-men- supposed to be? Surely not Latin? If not, what then is "oldest form" supposed to mean?

The “Leiden school”, as exemplified by de Vaan’s etymological dictionary, posits the PIE form *h3neh3-mn-, zero-grade *h3nh3-mn-. The first laryngeal would explain the initial o- in Greek onoma; the second laryngeal would account for the long vowel in Latin nōmen. This theory relieves us of having to posit an ambiguous vowel in the first syllable.